# Extract text in a <p>... </p> paragraph element

Tags: android, string, parsing

I have a string like

```
some text <p>any text</p>
```

from which I need to remove the part

```
<p>any text</p>
```

and as a result, get the string

```
some text
```

I found some sample code from a tutorial to work with strings, but I don't understand how it works. I'm a newbie in coding and it's hard because I don't know English.

```
private String description;

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
    if (description.contains("<p>")) {
        String musor  = description.substring(description.indexOf("<p>"));
        String cleanUp = musor.substring(0, musor.indexOf("</p>")+1);
        musor = musor.substring(musor.indexOf("<p>"));
        this.description = this.description.replace(cleanUp, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe its help too android.text.Html.fromHtml(description).toString();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions which can do the trick.

```
String regexp = "<p>.*?</p>";
String replace = "";
myString.replaceAll(regexp, replace);
```

Replaces all `<p>`-tags and their contents with `​`. (See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/.)

I guess that there are a lot of libraries, which can do the same or even more.